# Can sum of two continuous random variables be discrete?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Lately I have been asked if there exist any two continuous random variables, whose sum is discrete random variable. Probably the good start is the definition of discrete and continuous random variables.

> If random variable has property $\sum_{x \in R} P(X=x) = 1$, the variable is discrete.
>
> Random variable is continuous if there exists function $f_X: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ which for each $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $P(X \in A) = \int_A f_X(x) \ dx$.

Than means $P(X = x) = 0$ for each $x$ if variable is continuous. That gives me *feeling* that sum of two continuous random variables cannot be discrete, but I have no idea if I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible for the sum of continuous random variables to be discrete: if $X$ is a continuous random variable, then so is $-X$, and $X+(-X)=0$, which is a discrete random variable.

Comment: Oh, right, it is pretty simple. It wasn't part of the question, but now I am thinking about their independence - they are **not** independent, right? If so, are there two independent continuous random variables, whose sum is discrete?

Comment: No: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with pdfs $f$ and $g$, then the sum $X+Y$ has a pdf given by the convolution of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Complement: If $X, Y$ are independent and one of it has pdf, then the sum $X+Y$ has a pdf also.

Comment: Dumb question, but wouldn't the sum for all x over the 0 distribution still be 0 (not 1)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. $0$ refers to the constant random variable zero, i.e. the random variable which is equal to zero with probability $1$.