# Why does $X \neq Y$ almost surely holds if the distribution is continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that the distribution functions $F_X$ and $F_Y$ of $X$ and $Y$ are continuous. Why does then $X \neq Y$ holds almost surely (with respect to $\mathbb{P}$)?

Comment: Hint: draw the graph of $X=Y$ in the sample space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the random variable $X-Y$. 
Due to the continuity of distributions of $X, Y$ and their independence - this is a well defined random variable with a continuous distribution itself, given by the convolution.

For any Random Variable (say $V$) with a continuous distribution; probability of a single point is zero, $\mathcal{P}(V=r) = 0 \hspace{1em} \forall r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, $\mathcal{P}(X=Y) = 0 = \mathcal{P}(X-Y=0) $

Which means $\mathcal{P}(X \neq Y) = 1$, which is the definition of almost surity.

Comment: Should be noted that independence is important for the first assertion. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141568/can-sum-of-two-continuous-random-variables-be-discrete).

Comment: You're right @Snoop, I have added that. Thanks!